# Как найти вхождение подстроки в столбце dataframe python(pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Задача такова: необходимо найти вхождение подстроки в каждой строке столбца Name, DataFrame называется data. Делаю так, но ничего не получается:

```
data.Name.index(',')
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать!

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-pandas-numpy-scipy-scikit-learn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы вычленить часть строки вам не нужно знать индекс ее начала.

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [30]: df
Out[30]:
                 name
0    яблоко, апельсин
1  банан, киви, манго
```

разбиваем по запятым, возвращаем первый элемент:

```
In [31]: df.name.str.split(r',\s*').str[0]
Out[31]:
0    яблоко
1     банан
Name: name, dtype: object
```

или парсим все до первой запятой:

```
In [32]: df.name.str.extract(r'([^,]*)', expand=False)
Out[32]:
0    яблоко
1     банан
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Спасибо! А что значит параметр r в методе split и extract?

Comment: @piller97, это ["raw string"](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html), позволяющий не экранировать лишний раз спец. символы

Comment: Ясно, спасибо!)

Comment: Если бы вы сразу привели пример входных/выходных данных, то получили бы ответ на 18-19 часов раньше ;-)

Comment: Я думал, так разберусь))

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы индекс подстроки в каждой строке колонки `Name` найти:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Name=['abc', 'def']))
>>> df.Name.str.find('b')
0    1
1   -1
Name: Name, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как потом сделать срез строк? Ну, то есть чтобы бы было примерно так: data.Name[data.Name.str.find(', '):]?

Comment: @piller97: что вы хотите получить если `','` нет в строке? Создайте минимальный пример ввода/вывода, который интересные вам случаи представляет, опубликуйте как отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос.

Comment: в общем, надо в каждой строке отмахнуть левую часть с запятой. Например, "яблоко, апельсин" -> "апельсин".
Пытаюсь сделать так: print(data.Name.str.slice(start = data.Name.str.index(','))), но выводится NaN